# How to display "-->" in php?

Tags: php, database, comments

I get data from other sites and I can't revise them.
However, there are some data like this.

```
A --> B
A --> C
```

So if my SQL result contains the above data, it becomes comments and display php codes.
Other special characters(ex: -, :, [,]..) are displayed well.

How can I handle this?
Here is my code. $bus contains '-->'

```
@foreach ($bus['bus_infos2'] as $bus)
      <li>{{$bus->name}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: what code you have so far so we can fix it.

Comment: It also looks like you're using a templating engine with `{{}}`. It may have its own methods for escaping HTML characters.

Comment: If the result of `$bus->name` is `A --> B`, then you could use `htmlspecialchars` : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php